# ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_SIGNATURE_FAILED when reading smart card

Tags: node.js, reactjs, certificate, smartcard, ssl-client-authentication

I am developing a web app with React (front-end) and Nodejs (back-end) and I need to use digital certificates to authenticate.

The options given to the server are:

```
  key: fs.readFileSync('./certs/localhost_key.pem'),
    cert: fs.readFileSync('./certs/localhost_cert.pem'),
    requestCert: true , rejectUnauthorized: false,
    ca: [
    fs.readFileSync('./certs/ACCVCA120.crt')
  ]
}
```

Once you select the certificate, the line which reads the certificate from the back-end is `let cert = req.connection.getPeerCertificate()`, and the front-end calls the endpoint which owns that line to read it.

If I use a certificate which is stored on the computer, the app reads the certificate properly, but if it reads it from a smart card, I get the following error after selecting the certificate: **net::ERR_SSL_CLIENT_AUTH_SIGNATURE_FAILED**.

¿Could you provide me a way to solve this error?

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I solved the problem, I let the solution here.

I was using the flag `--tls-min-v1.0` because I need it to establish a secure connection with Active Directory.

To perform the smart card reading I need a newer TLS version, at least TLS 1.2, so the reading was failing.

If I used the newer TLS version, the AD connection failed, so finally the solution was adding two flags:

- `--tls-min-v1.0`
- `--tls-max-v1.2`